# Sonar and TFS 2013 : No ProjectInfo.xml files were found

Tags: tfs, msbuild, sonarqube, sonar-runner

When I run TFS 2013 with sonar I get the following error: `No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being built.`

Message: `TF270015: 'SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.`

I use :

- sonarqube-5.1.zip
- sonar-csharp-plugin-4.0.jar
- SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner-0.9.zip
- sonar-runner-dist-2.4.zip

I've followed instructions found in "SonarQube Installation Guide for Existing TFS Environment.pdf".

Any help ?

Thank you.

Log :

```
SonarQube Analysis Summary
Analysis failed for SonarQube project "WpfApplication2", version 1.0
Product projects: 0, test projects: 0
Invalid projects: 0, skipped projects: 0, excluded projects: 0
Résumé
Debug | x86
0 erreur(s), 1 avertissement(s)
$/Essai2/WpfApplication2/WpfApplication2.sln - 0 erreur(s), 1 avertissement(s),
Afficher le fichier journal
C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\src\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2.sln.metaproj : The specified solution configuration "Debug|x86" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration.
$/Essai2/WpfApplication2/WpfApplication2.sln compilé
Aucun résultat des tests
Aucun résultat de couverture du code
Autres erreurs et avertissements
2 erreur(s), 0 avertissement(s)
01:45:52: No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being built.
Exception Message: TF270015: 'SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

Here is the Diagnostic (I truncated the source check out part) :

```
Compile, Test and Publish00:00:46


Run optional script before MSBuild00:00:08

InputsEnvironmentVariables: 
Enabled: True
Arguments: /key:WpfApplication2 /name:WpfApplication2 /version:1.0
FilePath: C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe

OutputsResult: 0

C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe /key:WpfApplication2 /name:WpfApplication2 /version:1.0

Pre-processing (3 arguments passed)

Using environment variables to determine the download directory...

Using environment variable 'TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY', value 'C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2'

Creating the analysis bin directory: C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\bin

SonarQube server url: http://localhost:9000

Downloading SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip from http://localhost:9000/static/csharp/SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip to C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.Implementation.zip

Executing file C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.PreProcessor.exe

Args: "/key:WpfApplication2" "/name:WpfApplication2" "/version:1.0"

Working directory: C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\bin

Timeout (ms):300000

Process id: 4168

01:45:11: The path to the sonar-runner.properties file was not supplied on the command line. Attempting to locate the file...

01:45:11: Located the runner properties file: C:\sonar-runner-2.4\conf\sonar-runner.properties

01:45:11: Legacy TeamBuild environment detected

01:45:11: Creating config and output folders...

01:45:11: Removing the existing directory: C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\conf

01:45:11: Creating directory: C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\conf

01:45:11: Removing the existing directory: C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\out

01:45:11: Creating directory: C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\out

Generating the FxCop ruleset...

01:45:14: Saving the config file to C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml

Process returned exit code 0


Run MSBuild00:00:12

InputsProjectsToBuild: String[] Array
MSBuildMultiProc: True
Verbosity: Normal
ToolPlatform: Auto
Targets: 
RunCodeAnalysis: AsConfigured
CommandLineArguments: /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU"
ConfigurationsToBuild: String[] Array
OutputLocation: SingleFolder
Enabled: True
ToolVersion: 
CleanBuild: True
OutDir: 
RestoreNuGetPackages: True

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\nuget.exe restore "C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\src\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2.sln" -NonInteractive 

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe /nologo /noconsolelogger "C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\src\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2.sln" /nr:False /fl /flp:"logfile=C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\src\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2.log;encoding=Unicode;verbosity=normal" /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU" /m /p:OutDir="C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\bin\\" /p:Configuration="Debug" /p:Platform="x86" /p:VCBuildOverride="C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\src\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2.sln.x86.Debug.vsprops" /dl:WorkflowCentralLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;BuildUri=vstfs:///Build/Build/52;IgnoreDuplicateProjects=False;InformationNodeId=12;TargetsNotLogged=GetNativeManifest,GetCopyToOutputDirectoryItems,GetTargetPath;LogProjectNodes=True;LogWarnings=True;TFSUrl=http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection;"*WorkflowForwardingLogger,"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Tools\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.Logger.dll";"Verbosity=Normal;" /p:BuildId="dbda6e4d-d5bc-4eed-8b3e-6cc79e3721cc,vstfs:///Build/Build/52" /p:BuildLabel="WpfApplication2_20150615.3" /p:BuildTimestamp="Mon, 15 Jun 2015 11:44:59 GMT" /p:BuildSourceVersion="LWpfApplication2_20150615.3@$/Essai2" /p:BuildDefinition="WpfApplication2"


Run optional script after MSBuild00:00:00

InputsEnvironmentVariables: 
Enabled: True
Arguments: 
FilePath: 

OutputsResult: 0


Run optional script before Test Runner00:00:00

InputsEnvironmentVariables: 
Enabled: True
Arguments: 
FilePath: 

OutputsResult: 0


Run VS Test Runner00:00:00

InputsTestSpecs: BuildParameter[] Array
Enabled: False
ConfigurationsToTest: String[] Array
OutDir: 

This activity was not run since its Enabled property was set to False.


Run optional script after Test Runner00:00:25

InputsEnvironmentVariables: 
Enabled: True
Arguments: 
FilePath: C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe

OutputsResult: 0

C:\sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe

Post-processing (no arguments passed)

Using environment variables to determine the download directory...

Using environment variable 'TF_BUILD_BUILDDIRECTORY', value 'C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2'

Executing file C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.PostProcessor.exe

Args:

Working directory: C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\bin

Timeout (ms):3600000

Process id: 6548

01:45:28: Legacy TeamBuild environment detected

01:45:28: Loading the SonarQube analysis config from C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml

01:45:28: Legacy TeamBuild environment detected

01:45:28: Attempting to locate the CodeCoverage.exe tool...

01:45:28: Code coverage command line tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe

01:45:28: Fetching code coverage report information from TFS...

01:45:28: Connecting to TFS...

01:45:29: Fetching build information...

01:45:30: Fetch code coverage report info...

01:45:52: Operation timed out, Elapsed time (ms): 20358

01:45:52: ...done.

01:45:52: No code coverage reports were found for the current build.

01:45:52: Generating SonarQube project properties file to C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\out\sonar-project.properties

01:45:52: No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being built.

01:45:52: Writing processing summary to C:\Builds\1\Essai2\WpfApplication2\sqtemp\out\ProjectInfo.log

01:45:52: Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.

01:45:52: Updating the TeamBuild summary...

Process returned exit code 1

 Exception Message: TF270015: 'SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'. See the build logs for more details. (type UnexpectedExitCodeException) Exception Stack Trace: at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation) 


Handle Exception
```

Comment: Did you deploy the .targets file to the special folder under c:\Program Files\MSBuild\....\ImportsBefore?

Comment: It also would make sense to send the build logs

Comment: Hi Dinesh.  Yes, I did deploy SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets to C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Microsoft.Common.Targets\ImportBefore

Comment: @Dinesh Bolkensteyn  : I've added the log

Answer (score 7):

## Troubleshooting issues with the MSBuild.Runner v0.9

The following information is provided to help troubleshooting issues with version 0.9 of the MSBuild.Runner. The behaviour may change in later versions.

Most serious configuration issues will result in warnings or errors that will appear on the Build Summary page. In cases in which there are no errors or warnings reported, check the TFS TeamBuild diagnostic output (click on "Diagnostics" link at the top of the build summary report in Visual Studio). Both the pre- and post-processor steps log quite a lot of information to help diagnose issues.

### 1. Check the SonarQube Analysis Summary section appears in the Build Summary Report

The section should look like this:

```
SonarQube Analysis Summary
Analysis failed for SonarQube project "Simple console app", version 1.0
  Product projects: 4, test projects: 2
  Invalid projects: 0, skipped projects: 0, excluded projects: 0
```

If the section does not appear on the build summary page then there are configuration issues with the build agent, build definition, or both. Read the steps below to diagnose these further.

1.1 Check the number of projects that are reported in the summary

If no projects were found then it suggests that the integration targets are not being imported and used during the build.

If all of the projects are marked as invalid, it is likely that you are building more than one configuration e.g. [release or debug] | [x86 or x64]. You should also get an error saying no ProjectInfo.xml files could be found.

You can only analyse one configuration at a time. If you want to analyze both release and debug builds, then you will need to create a separate build definition for each, using different SonarQube project ids.

The diagnostic log will contain more infomation about why a project was invalid, which is normally because the project doesn't have a guid, or the guid is not unique. The normal reason for a non-unique guid is that you are building multiple configurations e.g. release and debug.

### 2. Check that the pre-build step is being executed

The diagnostic output should contain output similar to the following:

> Run optional script before MSBuild
>
> C:\SonarQube\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe /key:MyProject /name:"My Project" /version:1.0
>
> Pre-processing (3 arguments passed)

If it doesn't, check that the you are correctly calling SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe in the "Pre-build script" step in the build definition. An easy mistake is to put the script parameters in the wrong box by setting the "Post-build" properties instead (unhelpfully, the Post-build fields in the UI appear before the Pre-build fields).

### 2. Check that the post-build step is being executed

The diagnostic output should contain output similar to the following:

> Run optional script after Test Runner
>
> C:\SonarQube\bin\SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe
>
> Post-processing (no arguments passed)

If it doesn't, check that the you are correctly calling SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe in the "Post-test script" step in the build definition.

### 3. Check the rest of the diagnostic log

If the pre- and post- build steps are being executed correctly, check the rest of the diagnostic output for any clues as to what isn't working. Pay particular attention to messages from the pre- and post-processor about the directories and files they are writing to.

### 4. Check the files that have been created on the build agent

The analysis process creates temporary files under the build directory under a folder called SQTemp in v0.9.
Examining the contents of the folders can help determine the stage at which the analysis is failing.

The expected folders are as follows:

- bin: this folder contains the analysis targets and binaries. It is created by the SonarQube.MSBuild.Runner.exe which downloads the files from the SonarQube server. If this folder does not exist or is empty then the analysis failed at a very early stage and there should warnings or errors. Check that the C# plugin v4 is installed correctly on the SonarQube server, and that the SonarQube has been restarted since the plugin was installed.
- conf: this folder is created during pre-processing and contains the settings downloaded from the SonarQube server. If there are any FxCop rules active in the SonarQube the folder should contain an FxCop ruleset.
- out: this folder is populated during the MSBuild phase. It should contain one folder per project being built. It will also contain the generated sonar-project.properties file that is passed to the sonar-runner. If the folder is empty then it is possible the SonarQube.Integration.targets are not being imported correctly. 
  The error message "No ProjectInfo.xml files were found" will normally appear in this case. The ProjectInfo.xml files are generated by the target "WriteSonarQubeData" in the SonarQube.Integration.targets, so the next thing to check is that SonarQube.Integration.targets are being imported correctly and the expected targets are being executed.

### 5. Checking the SonarQube.Integration.targets are imported and called

Firstly, double-check the installation of the SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets file:

- check it is in the correct folder for the version of MSBuild you are using i.e. %ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\[12.0 or 14.0]\Microsoft.Common.Targets\ImportBefore
- check for typos in the folder name "ImportBefore" (should be singular, not plural)
  (Thanks to Richard from [BlackMarble](http://www.blackmarble.co.uk/) for this tip).

If the targets are installed correctly then you will need to increase the verbosity of the MSBuild logging to diagnostic and build again so you can check the detailed MSBuild output. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a simple way to increase the verbosity of the MSBuild logs when running under TeamBuild 2013. You can produce an additional log file with more detail, but you will need access to the build agent machine to pick up the log file.

To create an MSBuild log with more detailed info:

- select "Queue New Build" from the BUILD menu in Visual Studio
- click on the "Parameters" tab.
- Expand the "2. Build" section and the "5. Advanced" sections
- Set the "MSBuild arguments" property to the following:
  /m:1 /fl2 /flp2:"verbosity=diagnostic"
  The "/m:1" tells MSBuild not to build in parallel which can make the log easier to read. The other two parameters  tell MSBuild to log to a file. See the MSBuild command line help for more info.
- Click "Queue" and wait for the build to finish.
- Find and open the log on the build agent. It should be called msbuild2.log and be under the source directory for your build definition.

If the SonarQube.Intergration.ImportBefore.targets are being executed, there will be a log entry saying the "SonarQubeImportBeforeInfo" target was executed. There should be some output message saying whether the file "SonarQube.Integration.targets" was located or not.

The ProjectInfo.xml files are written by the target "WriteSonarQubeProjectData". The log should show that this target has been executed, and the "WriteProjectInfoFile" task has executed. If not, the log should give an idea of why the targets were skipped.

Comment: Hi @duncanpMS ! Thank you for your help.  I've added the diagnostic.  The code you gave is present in the logs.  Further down I read the same error message :     No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being built.

Comment: @Mli: your TFS diagnostic logs look ok so it looks like a problem with importing or executing the targets. I've edited my previous answer to provide more information on troubleshooting those issues.

Comment: Hi !   Thank you a lot. It was a great help. I checked it all, but the issue was due to the x86 / x64 configuration for tests and Debug build...  I don't know exactly what happened, but it works.    Now I get another issue : the unit tests are not executed... I'll create a nexw thread in this forum.

Comment: This question is ANSWERED, but when I try to change the status I get an error !

Comment: @Mli Your original ProjectInfo.xml issue would have occurred if you were building multiple configurations in the same build definition e.g. x86 and x64. You can only analyse one at a time. I've updated the troubleshooting notes above with more info.

Comment: Appendix to the missing `SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets` problem: just spent a few hours to find out that I had this target file in `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore` location. The problem was that besides this `4.0` directory I had `12.0` and `14.0` as well. The MSBuild runner placed this file in `12.0` and `14.0` dirs only and the MSBuild apparently looked into the `4.0` location where the `.targets` was missing. Oh, God.

Comment: As of v1.0.2 the targets files are only deployed to the v12.0 and v14.0 MSBuild directories, and you need to build using the v12/v14 version of msbuild.exe (e.g. by building from a VS command prompt).

Comment: I'm having the issue of missing the .targets file when running the runner v1.0.2 in Jenkins.

I'm using the jenkins plugin and the preprocess seems to run ok, as does the post process. Except that the .targets file, which does exist in the .sonar folder in the workspace root, never gets called.

Any ideas on how to get it to pick up the targets file?