# Configuring TFS 2013 has build issues with SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

I have configured SonarQube to work with my TFS 2013. I followed the steps as mentioned in the setup doc. When i try to give a build from TFS online or Visual Studio, I am able to successfully complete the steps before `Finish the analysis and upload the results to SonarQube`.

I get the error `No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being built`.

I am unable to figure out what might me causing the issue. I checked one of the links : [No ProjectInfo.xml files were found error from command prompt using MSBuild SonarQube Runner v1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505626/no-projectinfo-xml-files-were-found-error-from-command-prompt-using-msbuild-sona) which speaks about the command prompt. Can someone point out where the issue is?

Below is the error log:

```
2015-09-12T11:44:10.9194896Z Output directory: C:\a\6fb08ad4\.sonarqube\out

2015-09-12T11:44:10.9194896Z Config file: C:\a\6fb08ad4\.sonarqube\out

2015-09-12T11:44:10.9204886Z 11:44:10 AM  Loading the SonarQube analysis config from C:\a\6fb08ad4\.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeAnalysisConfig.xml

2015-09-12T11:44:10.9204886Z 11:44:10 AM  Attempting to locate the CodeCoverage.exe tool...

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3231261Z 11:44:11 AM  Multiple versions of VS are installed: 11, 12, 14

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3240831Z 11:44:11 AM  Code coverage command line tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3240831Z 11:44:11 AM  Fetching code coverage report information from TFS...

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3250829Z 11:44:11 AM  Attempting to locate a test results (.trx) file...

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3250829Z 11:44:11 AM  No test results files found

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3260828Z 11:44:11 AM  Generating SonarQube project properties file to C:\a\6fb08ad4\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3270789Z ##[error]11:44:11 AM  No ProjectInfo.xml files were found. Check that the analysis targets are referenced by the MSBuild projects being built.

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3270789Z 11:44:11 AM  Writing processing summary to C:\a\6fb08ad4\.sonarqube\out\ProjectInfo.log

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3270789Z 11:44:11 AM  Generation of the sonar-properties file failed. Unable to complete SonarQube analysis.

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3280797Z 11:44:11 AM  Creating a summary markdown file...

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3280797Z Process returned exit code 1

2015-09-12T11:44:11.3290776Z ##[error]Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

2015-09-12T11:44:11.5740896Z ##[error]Unexpected exit code received from batch file: 1

2015-09-12T11:44:11.5790878Z ##[debug]summaryMdPath = C:\a\6fb08ad4\.sonarqube\out\summary.md

2015-09-12T11:44:11.5820880Z ##[debug]Uploading the summary.md file
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843177/sonar-and-tfs-2013-no-projectinfo-xml-files-were-found/30894558#30894558.
The post refers to v0.9 but applies equally to v1.0 and v1.0.1.
From the look of your log, the pre-process step is running correctly, so check that the targets are being imported correctly into your projects (see the section "5. Checking the SonarQube.Integration.targets are imported and called" in the troubleshooting post).

Comment: @Shermin, do you queue the build in TFS2013 or in Visual Studio Online?

Comment: @Vicky , I am using Visual Studio online for tfs build

Comment: @duncanpMS, I don't see 'SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets' being created in my folder as specified in section.5, Is it something that we need to create or is i autogenerated?

Comment: @SherminSebastian, if you work with VSO, then do you set up your own build agent, install Java, and setup the MSBuild.SonarQube Runner on that agent? Check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/08/24/build-tasks-for-sonarqube-analysis.aspx